# Android Api Level: Target Model vs. Manifest minimum

Tags: android

If you start a project and select the target model to be api 8. But then go to the manifest and specify the minimum is 4. And then your app is simple lets just say it is hello, world. Will it still work on a api 4 or must have i selected that as my build target? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It will work on an api 4 device **provided** you did not calls any post-level 4 api calls. The surest way to check that is to temporarily set your target level to 4 and see if any problems crop up in the build.